# New RSQ-CBWD-003 keyboard not working

Tags: keyboard

I've bought myself a [new keyboard](https://www.lostelecom.ru/komplekt-klaviatura-mysh-rsq-rsq-cbwd-003) and plug it in, but it doesn't work properly: several keys (the middle row from 'A' to '"') are not working. I think it is because I had a generic pc105 keyboard before, and this keyboard is some other kind:

```
cat /etc/default/keyboard 
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us,ru"
XKBVARIANT=","
XKBOPTIONS="grp:ctrl_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

I could try edit the /etc/default/keyboard, but I don't know what is the model for this keyboard, could you tell me? Also, what other reasons may be for this malfunction? I tried booting from LiveCD, but again Linux thinks that it is Generic pc105 keyboard and the keys not working. Thanks!

EDIT:

```
xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳  USB OPTICAL MOUSE                        id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SEM USB Keyboard                          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SEM USB Keyboard                          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Eee PC WMI hotkeys                        id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SEM USB Keyboard                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Add the output of `xinput list`. Test those keys with `showkey -a`.

Comment: @PabloA, I've edited the post, added xinput list output. The keys that doesn't work also doesn't show up in showkey -a.

Comment: Try on other computer and play around with `showkey`/`xev`, but probably is a hardware issue.